# Usage of Definition in front of Functionname

Tags: c++, sqlite

I just started using sqlite with C++ (im not really confident with C++ in general yet so this might be an obvious one).

I downloaded the sqlite sources and looked through the header file for a bit.
I noticed the following definition:

```
#ifndef SQLITE_API
#define SQLITE_API
#endif
```

So far i didnt thought anything of it but then i saw this:

```
SQLITE_API int sqlite3_threadsafe(void);
```

**The actual Question**

Why is this Definition used in front of the return type? What does it do or is it good for?

Thanks in advance

Comment: C and C++ are not the same thing; don't add unrelated language tags.

Comment: I added C++ because i use C++ to acces the API and C because the SQLite Sources are written in C.

Comment: @Simplex-- that's not entirely unreasonable, but it seems that your question is really about the C++ code you are using. If you feel like the C tag is appropriate to your question, please feel free to put it back.